# Can't connect to Mongo DB in .Net Core API

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, docker, .net-core

Been working on a .Net Core web app and right now I want to connect Mongo with the API that is written in .Net C# on .Net Core.  However, everything is inside Docker.  That being said, each element is is working.  I can edit the database from the command line so I know its up and running.  Also, I should note I am on the latest Ubuntu.

In the .csproj file I added Mongo drivers:

```
<PackageReference Include="MongoDB.Driver.Core" Version="2.3.0" />
<PackageReference Include="MongoDB.Bson" Version="2.3.0" />
```

And in the program.cs file I add:

```
using MongoDB.Driver; // at top
using MongoDB.Bson;
...
...
var mongo = MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017"); // in main method
```

This is the error I get when I build the app with docker:

```
Program.cs(13,25): error CS0103: The name 'MongoClient' does not exist in the current context [/src/src/Identity.api/Identity.api.csproj]
```

Did I add the right drivers, are they in the wrong spot?

Let me know if any additional info is needed. Thanks so much, I look forward to being able to connect to the DB!

Comment: It seems it cannot find the class MongoClient. You probably didn't add the dll's (or lib?) correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient` type is contained in the `MongoDB.Driver` package, so you need to reference that, `MongoDB.Driver.Core` is not enough.

`MongoDB.Driver.Core` contains the "core component" of the MongoDB .Net driver, not the .Net Core version of the driver.

Comment: Should I add all three drivers to the .csproj and to the program.cs file?

Comment: Adding just `MongoDB.Driver` to csproj is enough, since that package references the other two packages. For namespaces, it depends on what types you need. If it's just `MongoClient`, then `MongoDB.Driver` is enough. If you need more types, you might need other namespaces.

Comment: So, I added:

var mongo = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017");
            var db = mongo.GetDatabase("cvpz");   
            db.getCollection("people");

But it says its not part of the mongo definition.  Do I need to add something more?

Comment: @Joel I was answering a question about NuGet packages. I don't actually know anything about Mongo. You might want to ask a new question about that.